# Как получить значение opacity?

Tags: javascript

В css задано свойство opacity:

```
#something
{
    opacity: .5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body id="something">
```

Как мне получить значение этого свойства в Javasciprt? Нужен точный ответ того, кто точно знает.

Comment: На webew есть [статья](http://webew.ru/articles/1830.webew) по этому поводу. Поизучайте ее. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}

alert(getStyle("something", "opacity"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Давайте заменим слово f**k на di

```
document.getElementById('di').style.opacity
```

Comment: Почему тогда alert вашей записи выводит undefined??

Comment: Значит программно не установлена.

Comment: А если вручную установить значение не выведет?

Comment: По крайней мере должен, из-за разных браузеров, разные значения возвращаются.

Comment: В IE выводит undefined, в firefox выводит пустое значение.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#something").css("opacity");
```

Если Вам интересно посмотреть на наиболее полный фрагмент кода, то вот так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("opacity: " + $("#something").css("opacity"));
});
</script>
<style>
#something { opacity: 0.45; }
</style>
<body id="something">
</body>
```

Comment: Извините, но мне очень важно это сделать на чистом JS

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document.body).css("opacity");
```

Используется библиотека jQuery.

Постарайтесь *использовать* разметку и *не использовать* неформальную лексику.

О том, как использовать разметку [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/markdown_help/).